# MongoDb and Spring Boot - There is an error of creating datasource

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

- I have configured a Docker container with mongoDB.
- Then I created pom.xml.

```xml
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mapstruct}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>29.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

During starting an application has been appearing an error :

```
> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attemp
t: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsati
sfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' d
efined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is o
rg.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org
.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2020-08-02 20:24:51.308  INFO 117100 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

 **Failed to determine a suitable driver class**...
```

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

```
server.port=8099

#spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin

spring.data.mongodb.database=mongo-spring

spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=root

spring.data.mongodb.host=192.168.99.100
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

This dependency should be not exist, since Spring boot will try to configure working with MongoDb via the JDB abstraction, i.e. it will try to find a jdbc driver for MongoDb.

So, I cannot use into an application two different datasource, such as  for example: MySql and MongoDb.

Why?

Can anyone explain this more clearly, why so and whether it is still possible to find a way out and use 2 such data sources, of course, given that all this should be automatically configured and collected by maven?

Comment: Please update your post: copy/paste the error message

Comment: `[..]$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class`. Please show the relevant config.

Comment: What is your exact goal there? Basically you have a dependency to `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` but you don't specify `spring.datasource.url`. Therefore, Spring does not know, which driver it should use